# Big Sur causes failure to launch of Automator scripts

Tags: notifications

An Automator task runs an rclone script for backups. This  is scheduled in the Calendar. It worked fine in Catalina, but just when I  upgraded to Big Sur, I started seeing these alerts whenever the script was supposed to run. The script runs fine from the terminal.

It appears that Automator (or at least "Automation", the closest I could find) has permissions.

How can I allow rclone to run?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's probably a result of the increased security that prevents users from running their software. ;-) Check that rclone does launch without incident in the Finder. You may need to add Automator, or sh, or something to some of the System Preferences Security's panels. I suggest Full Disk Access, and Developer Tools. See if anything in Automation needs ticking, too.

Comment: Thank you. The rclone script runs fine from the Terminal. It appears that Automator (or at least "Automation", the closest I could fine) has permissions. See screenshot above. How else would I give permissions to Automator?

Comment: Deleting everything and redoing the whole Automator alarm solved this. Makes no sense, so I attribute this to changes in the Big Sur security model that I do not quite understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleting everything and redoing the whole Automator alarm solved this. Makes no sense, so I attribute this to changes in the Big Sur security model that I do not quite understand.